# Union range that fall below one another - VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to union two ranges that fall below one another to perform multiple regression.

This example will make my question clear..

Say I read in range A1:A5 and A:6 to A:10 as parameters in my function.
I then want to create a 5x2 matrix with these two ranges next to one another and assign it to a variable.

I require the data in this format so I can then regress it on another variable containing say the range B1:B5.

Resorting the data in the sheets is not ideal as I need to do this a number of times and just rolling down the data each time.

Any help is greatly appreciated, kind regards.

This is my code so far:

```
Function Dimson1Yearly(y_range, x_range1, x_range2, x_range3)

Dim entireRange As Variant
Dim i As Integer

entireRange = Application.Union(x_range1, x_range2, x_range3)


Dim RegressionStats As Variant
RegressionStats = WorksheetFunction.LinEst(y_range, entireRange, True, True)

Dim j As Integer
Dim sum As Double
sum = 0

For j = 1 To 3
    sum = sum + RegressionStats(1, j)
Next

Dimson1Yearly = sum

End Function
```

Note: It works fine when the x ranges that are chosen are next to each other but not when below - i.e. from the same column

Comment: I have used the Union method but doesn't work, somehow excel still recognizes that data are from the same column and so Linest function doesn't work

Comment: If you have code, you should include it in your question: it will increase your chances of getting a useful response, and also helps to explain exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks Timm, the For loop is just summing up the statistics that I require for this particular procedure

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Set`

```
Set entireRange = Application.Union(x_range1, x_range2, x_range3)
```

with object variables.

You should use `Dim entireRange As Range` if you know that it will be a Range, this will make it easier to spot problems. However, if you are using your function in the worksheet, you will need to use a breakpoint to discover this. Even then it is a little tricky. The best way is the view the Immediate Window (Ctrl-G) and try to execute the function from there using:

```
?Dimson1Yearly(range("a1"),range("b4"),range("d6"),range("e7"))
```

If you have used `Dim entireRange As Range` then you will receive the error "Object Variable or With Block Variable not set".

Comment: Thanks Andy, I've discovered where the error is. Union is combining the data one below the other. I want to combine the ranges one next to each other. Any suggestions?